# Where are admin/config/user-interface/archive setting stored

Tags: 7

Where are these settings stored at. On the disk? In a database table?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, configurations in administrative pages are saved into `variable` table.

The path `admin/config/user-interface/archive` is not a Drupal core path. It must have been provided by a module. If you want to get a definitive answer, you should provide more information.

Comment: I need to update this data but I can only do it via a sql update. I can't do it via the user interface. The form tag uses the id tag of "archive-admin-settings" but I don't see that in the variable table.

Comment: Generally you can just look at the inputs @Alex. The `name` attribute specifically will usually correspond to the name of the variable in the DB table, assuming the form's been built with `system_settings_form`. The values are stored as PHP serialised strings, though, so updating them via plain SQL could be quite a task